# Как нарисовать круги на Яндекс картах?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Необходимо нарисовать круги на карте с центром круга - адрес на карте. Получила АПИ ключ, вставляю в строку поиска этот ключ, по инструкции. Всплывает блокнот с множеством кодов. Так как я не владею навыками программирования ни на каком вообще языке,  я не понимаю, что мне необходимо сделать, куда прописывать специальные коды для создания кругов. Как узнать установлены ли Пакеты? Где это можно посмотреть?

Comment: вы это хотите получить на своём сайте? И какие пакеты вы имеете в виду?

Comment: у нас на сайте есть карта, где указаны объекты. мы хотим создать карту, где есть круги. центр круга эти точки. но не понятно куда нужно писать коды для их создания.

Comment: читая другие запросы про рисование кругов, там писали комментарии, что должны быть установлены пакеты

Answer (score 0):

1. Заходим на страницу конструктора: https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/
2. Выбираем инструмент «Многоугольники»
3. Последовательно отмечаем точки, обозначаем контур будущего района (белые точки).

Когда вы тянете за линию, появляются новые промежуточные точки, которыми можно исправлять контур. Чем крупнее масштаб, в котором идет отрисовка, тем точнее его границы.

4. Слева в Списке объектов появился район – укажите его описание в появившемся окошке. Здесь же, можно выбрать:

   Цвет, прозрачность и толщину контура
   Цвет и прозрачность заливки

Нажимаем «Готово» — район готов.

5. Далее нажимаем «Сохранить и продолжить»
6. Затем нужно указать тип карты:

   Интерактивный – в этом случае карту можно будет просматривать прямо на сайте, передвигать, менять масштаб. Такая карта используется в большинстве случаев;
   Статический – отображается простая картинка, являющаяся ссылкой на большую карту.
7. Размер карты: ширина и высота, в пикселях.

Если поставить галочку «Растянуть по ширине», это значит, карта займет по ширине всю доступную область страницы, на которой находится.

Размер можно менять, потянув за уголки окошка, в котором высейчас видите карту.

8. Масштаб меняется с помощью ползунка окошка. Я для этой цели использую нажатие клавиши Alt + колесико мышки. В таком масштабе карта изначально будет отображаться на вашем сайте.
9. Нажимаем «Получить код карты».

Если вам нужна только ссылка на карту, тогда скопируйте её в нижнем поле.
Подробнее тут(источник) https://yvoloboy.ru/jandeks-karta-s-rajonami/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @NowhereMan 
Согласен с вами, исправил

Comment: @aleksandr barakin исправил тоже, спасибо за замечание

Comment: я понимаю, но мне нужен круг. я действую по всем возможным инструкциям.

Comment: я получили APIключ, пытаюсь вставить в строку поиска "По адресу api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/ находится загрузчик, который при обращении к нему подключает нужные компоненты API." может я куда то не туда вставляю? так же в поисковую строку вставила "https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0-stable/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" мне опять выдает ошибку, но при этом появился Блокнот с огромным количеством символов. не понимаю для чего нужен этот блокнот.

Comment: Не используйте архивные версии API. Актуальная сейчас 2.1.79 Никакие компоненты уже подключать не надо, они все грузятся автоматом https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/load.html

Comment: я правильно вставляю в поисковую строку? даже переделываю на актуальную версию "api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.79-stable/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&load=package.standard&lang=ru-RU" , вставляю свой APIключ. ничего не происходит. я уже теряю надежду, что у меня что то получиться. ведь я понимаю, что это не сложно. но у меня никак не получается. наверно я что то делаю не так.

Comment: можно прям как для тупого сказать? я использую редактирование и создание своих карт в яндекс картах, расставляю метки, это умею, могу отправить ссылку. но мне необходимо к этим меткам прикрепить круги. очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

Answer (score 0):

Простейший код для добавления окружностей с заданным центром и радиусом, [расширенная версия которого](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/circle) есть в песочнице Яндекс:

```
ymaps.ready(init);
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {center: [55.76, 37.64], zoom: 10});

    // Создаем круг.
    var myCircle = new ymaps.Circle([
        // Координаты центра круга.
        [55.76, 37.60],
        // Радиус круга в метрах.
        10000
    ]);

    // Добавляем круг на карту.
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myCircle);
}
```

Строка **var myMap...** задаёт центр карты (координаты и масштаб). У круга нужно как минимум указать его центр (широта и долгота в градусах) и радиус в метрах.

Comment: куда вставлять данный код? подскажите для особо одаренных, в какое окно данный код вставлять?)))))

Comment: В самом простом случае, то в блок <script></script> вашей HTML-страницы. Пример: https://jsbin.com/jacadew/1/edit?html,output